# Mercurial not showing folder src that is not ignored

Tags: android, mercurial, ignore, hgignore

I have an android project (Android studio) and for some unknown reason my app/src folder is being ignored by my Mercurial but that folder is not on my .hgignore file.  If I rename the folder to src2 it shows on my Sourcetree app, but if I keep the folder name as "src" it does not show.

Any ideas of why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a way to make the src folder appears on my SourceTree as "Uncommited Changes".

I had to manually add that "src" folder to the repo by doing via terminal;

```
hg add src
```

Still don't know the root cause for the issue (maybe a SourceTree bug?).